# Where can I find a list of Yii application events?

Tags: php, html, yii

I want to hook into some Yii application events but I cannot find any sort of documentation listing out the events available. All I have been able to find were a few pages on 'onBeginRequest' and 'onEndRequest'. Are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember having seen a complete list of all events of all classes, but if you browse through the documentation of the classes you need events for, you will find all there are...

For Example there are several in [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)

```
onAfterConstruct()

onBeforeFind()
onAfterFind()

onBeforeSave()
onAfterSave()

onBeforeValidate()
onAfterValidate()

onBeforeDelete()
onAfterDelete()
```

As those only apply to Active Records, they are only defined in that class.